# What should we do with tag dtgridview?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [dtgridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtgridview) was created ~7 years ago, but it is not used any more.

However, what should we do to handle this situation?

- Should it be removed?
- Should it be a suggestion to another master tag? Doesn't know?

Comment: What about going forward and remove the tag from those 2 questions? It'll disappear tomorrow.

Comment: It seems to come from [here](https://bitbucket.org/danielctull/dtkit/wiki/Home) and it was last updated on [October 23, 2009](https://bitbucket.org/danielctull/dtkit/commits/a853f97848d14ede03634494486e0532c87f62de). I'd say it's a dead project that nobody used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the existing questions with that tag should also be deleted, it’s not clear what would be gained by removing the tag.

I see there are just two questions with that tag, but if in fact those two questions are specifically about whatever `dtgridview` is, then it would seem like they’re tagged correctly and accurately.

And glancing at the content of those two questions, both do in fact appear to be very specifically about about `dtgridview` (whatever that is/was). And the questions don’t seem to be bad ones. Neither has any downvotes, and one of them has 4 upvotes and two upvoted answers.

So they’re decent questions with answers that at least a  people have found useful, and they’re tagged accurately. ∴ Doesn’t seem like there’s any SO-usage problem that needs fixing there.

---

As far as keeping around the questions themselves:

I realize if that tag hasn’t been used in ~7 years then it’s likely whatever the `dtgridview`-related software was used for in code previously, nobody’s probably using it enough for any new projects now to run into any problems they can’t solve on their own without needing to ask on SO.
But one of those questions has been visited 1,300+ times so far. Who knows when, but it’s possible a few people might occasionally still be finding that questions and its answers useful.

So even if this `dtgridview` software’s no longer in wide use, given how long software can live on longer after it’s been end-of-lifed or abandoned by its maintainers, it’s imaginable a developer out there may today be given the task of making some update or fix to some old code they’ve inherited that uses `dtgridview`, and they could run into the very same problem in that question, and one of the answers there that’s already been upvoted previously may be the answer they need.